# Threading Differences in Linux Subsystem For Windows

Tags: c, multithreading, ubuntu, pthreads, windows-10

Less of a programming question, and more of an oddity that I'm seeking clarification on. Consider the following C program:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>

volatile int counter = 0;

void incrementCounter()
{
    counter += 1;
}

void* threadfunc()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    {
        incrementCounter();
    }
}

int main()
{
    pthread_t tids[100];
    printf("Creating Threads...\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        pthread_create(&tids[i], NULL, threadfunc, NULL);
    }

    printf("Joining Threads...\n");

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        pthread_join(tids[i], NULL);
    }

    printf("Finished. Counter = %d\n", counter);
}
```

This was what I wrote for a college assignment. Its supposed to show the dangers of multiple threads not locking when writing to variables.

I'm on Windows 10, so I open up my installation of Ubuntu Bash, and run

```
$ gcc -std=c99 -pthread main.c
$ ./a.out
```

It prints

```
Creating Threads...
Joining threads...
Finished. Counter = 100000
```

Ok... that's correct. It shouldn't be correct. This is supposed to be broken!

I run it again and again with the same results. `Counter = 100000` each and every time! This may be the only time in my life that I'm disappointed my code works correctly.

So I log onto my schools shared Linux system for CS students. Pull my code, execute it the same way and I get:

```
Creating Threads...
Joining threads...
Finished. Counter = 99234
```

Next time, `Counter = 99900`, then `Counter = 100000`, then `Counter = 99082`

That's what I was expecting!

**So my question:**

What gives? What is it about the Linux Subsystem for Windows that causes my code not to break?

Comment: Is your installation of `Ubuntu` running in a virtual machine with a single CPU?

Comment: @Lou Linux Subsystem For Windows is not a virtual machine.

Comment: Standard install. Running on an i7 with 4 physical cores.

Comment: @n.m.: just noticed, I had no idea this thing existed until now. Presumably it does *some* thread virtualization under the hood, at least according to OP's observations. Perhaps it would be a good idea to [post a comment here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wsl/2016/05/23/pico-process-overview/) to get details about the inner workings.

Comment: *"I'm disappointed my code works correctly."* - an impossibility, as the code itself is not correct. I suggest you use a smaller pool of threads, and a *much* larger count up target. It is completely feasible that each thread your launching is already finished with its loop and terminating before the next thread from `main` is even spun up. And/or/also latch the beginning of each thread with a global mutex that is initially latched in `main`, and released only when all threads are started, with each thread releasing it as soon as they acquire it prior to starting their loop.

Comment: Undefined behaviour is *undefined*. This means no guarantees whatsoever. In particular, a result that looks OK is a permissible outcome for a program that exhibits UB.

You cannot expect a broken program to demonstrate a spectacular explosion for you each time you run it.

Comment: https://github.com/Microsoft/BashOnWindows/issues - is a good place to start research your issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Undefined, unspecified and implementation-defined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397984/undefined-unspecified-and-implementation-defined-behavior)

Comment: From what I've seen in the [WSL](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wsl/) blog, it appears that it's very conservative about creating a large number of threads and spawning them ahead of time, so what @WhozCraig wrote is likely true.

Comment: Yup - a loop to 1000 is next-to-nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is *still* broken. It just happened to work. You have *no* guarantees that the code will run correctly or *incorrectly*. You [still] have a *race condition* between the threads.

Herein, I'm using two threads: A and B. But, the example works for more threads.

On linux, you got:

```
thread A        thread B
-------------   --------------
fetch
                fetch
inc
                inc
store
                store
```

Here, thread B's store will trash thread A's increment and store. That is, if the original value was 5, you'll get 6 instead of the [desired] 7.

Under Windows, you got:

```
thread A        thread B
-------------   --------------
fetch
inc
store
                fetch
                inc
                store
```

But, the difference is just the OS scheduler and its policies. Without locking, there is no guarantee.

Under Windows, it started thread A, which ran to completion, before thread B got started and ran, so you get the "disjoint" behavior.

Try with a larger [or smaller] number of threads and a much larger thread loop value and you should see some different behavior

Comment: I am pretty sure OP already knows all this, the question was *why* the Ubuntu-on-Windows version doesn't exhibit the behavior. And there are 100 threads involved, not "thread A and B".

Comment: @Lou Thanks for pointing that out. Yes I understand that the code is horribly broken -- the assignment was to write horribly broken code.

Comment: @Craig Estey your suggestion was spot on. I upped it to 1000 threads counting to 10000 and I started seeing incorrect results. It was very infrequent -- maybe 5% of the time.