# Distributed Computing with PThread Not Working

Tags: arrays, c, linux, pthreads, distributed-computing

I have a program to write in C for a class I am taking. The objective is to take an array and count all the instances of a certain string using 10 different threads.  In this instance, we are trying to count how many "is" there are in the file.  Which should be 55.

My current logic was to split the array into each word and then process each word individually and include a test to see if it should be processed on the current thread or another thread.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  My instructor provided all code besides:
num_substring, allowedOnThread and counter. I made these.

I am very new to C.

I currently have:

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX 10240
#define NUM_THREADS  10

int n1,n2;
char *s1,*s2;
FILE *fp;
int countArray[NUM_THREADS]={0};

int total = 0;

//read input file and generate string s1/s2 and length n1/n2
int readf(FILE *fp)
{
    if((fp=fopen("strings.txt", "r"))==NULL){
        printf("ERROR: can't open string.txt!\n");
        return 0;
    }
    s1=(char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*MAX);
    if(s1==NULL){
        printf("ERROR: Out of memory!\n");
        return -1;
    }
    s2=(char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*MAX);
    if(s1==NULL){
        printf("ERROR: Out of memory\n");
        return -1;
    }
    /*read s1 s2 from the file*/
    s1=fgets(s1, MAX, fp);
    s2=fgets(s2, MAX, fp);
    n1=strlen(s1);  /*length of s1*/
    n2=strlen(s2)-1; /*length of s2*/

    if(s1==NULL || s2==NULL || n1<n2)  /*when error exit*/
        return -1;
    return 0;
}

int num_substring(int t) {
//add your logic here
//1, how to distribute different parts of string s1 into different threads
//2, how to sum up the total number of substring from all threads
    
    char *str = s1; // This is what we will need to process for the string
    
    char *token = strtok(str, " ");
    
    int count = 0;
    
    int index = 0;
    while(token != NULL) {
        // Determine if it should be on the thread
        
        if(allowedOnThread(t, index) == 1){
            count = count + counter(token);
        }else{
            return count;
        }
        index++;
        token = strtok(NULL, " ");
    }

    return count;
}

int allowedOnThread(int thread, int index) {
    int threadMultiplier = n1 / NUM_THREADS;
    
    // Check range
    int min = thread * threadMultiplier;
    int max = (thread * threadMultiplier) + threadMultiplier;
    
    if(thread >= 1){
        min = (thread * threadMultiplier) + 1;
    }
    
    if(thread + 1 == NUM_THREADS){
        max = n1 + 1;
    }
    
    if(min <= index && index <= max) {
        return 1;
    }
    
    
    return 0;
}

int counter(char *str){
    int i,j,k;
    int count;

    int complete = 0;
    
    for (i = 0; i <= (n1-n2); i++){   
        count=0;
        for(j = i,k = 0; k < n2; j++,k++){  /*search for the next string of size of n2*/  
            if (*(str+j)!=*(s2+k)){
                break;
            }else{
                count++;
            }

            if(count==n2){  
                complete++;
            }                       
        }
    }
    
    total = total + complete;
    
    return complete;
}


void *calSubStringThread(void *threadid){
    long tid = (long)threadid;
    printf("This is thread %ld, ", tid);
    int num = num_substring(tid);
    printf("find num of is: %d\n", num);
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    pthread_t threads[NUM_THREADS];
    int t, rc;

    readf(fp);
    
    for(t=0; t<NUM_THREADS; t++){
        rc = pthread_create(&threads[t], NULL, calSubStringThread, (void *) (size_t)t);
        if (rc){
            printf("ERROR; return code from pthread_create() is %d\n", rc);
            exit(-1);
        }
    }

    for(t=0; t<NUM_THREADS; t++){
        pthread_join(threads[t], NULL);
    }

    printf("The number of substrings is: %d\n", total);
    return 1;
}
```

Input file:

```
Thss is an apple. That ss a pear. That ss an orange. That ss a kiwi fruit. Thss ss an avocado. There ss a peach on the tree. Thss ss a banana. That ss a berry. That ss cherry. That ss a haw. Thss ss a lemon. There ss a hickory on the tree. Thss ss an apple. That ss a pear. That ss an orange. That ss a kiwi fruit. Thss ss an avocado. There ss a peach on the tree. Thss ss a banana. That ss a berry. That ss cherry. That ss a haw. Thss ss a lemon. There ss a hickory on the tree. Thss ss an apple. That ss a pear. This is an orange. That ss a kiwi fruit. Thss ss an avocado. There ss a peach on the tree. Thss ss a banana. That ss a berry. That ss ss. That ss a haw. Thss ss a lemon. There ss a hickory on the tree. Thss ss an apple. That ss a pear. That ss an orange. That ss a kiwi fruit. Thss ss an avocado. There ss a peach on the tree. Thss ss a banana. That ss a berry. That ss cherry. That ss a haw. Thss ss a lemon. There ss a hickory on the tree. Thss ss an apple. That ss a pear. That ss an orange. That is a kiwi fruit. This is an avocado. There ss a peach on the tree. Thss ss a banana. That ss a berry. That ss cherry. That ss a haw. Thss ss a lemon. There ss a hickory on the tree. Thss ss an apple. That ss a pear. That ss an orange. That ss a kiwi fruit. Thss ss an avocado. There ss a peach on the tree. Thss ss a banana. That ss a berry. That ss cherry. That ss a haw. Thss ss a lemon. There ss a hickory on the tree. Thss ss an apple. That ss a pear. That ss an orange. That ss a kiwi fruit. Thss ss an avocado. There ss a peach on the tree. This is a banana. This is a berry. That ss cherry. That ss a haw. Thss ss a lemon. There ss a hickory on the tree. Thss ss an apple. That ss a pear. That ss an orange. That ss a kiwi fruit. Thss ss an avocado. There ss a peach on the tree. Thss ss a banana. That ss a berry. That ss cherry. That ss a haw. Thss ss a lemon. There ss a hickory on the tree. Thss ss an apple. That ss a pear. That ss an orange. That ssss a kiwi fruit. Thss ss an avocado. There ss a peach on the tree. This is a banana. This is a berry. That is cherry. That ss a haw. Thss ss a lemon. There ss a hickory on the tree. Thss ss an apple. That ss a pear. That ss an orange. That ss a kiwi fruit. Thss ss an avocado. There ss a peach on the tree. Thss ss a banana. That ss a berry. That ss cherry. That ss a haw. Thss ss a lemon. There ss a hickory on the tree. Thss ss an apple. That ss a pear. That ss an orange. That ss a kiwi fruit. Thss ss an avocado. There ss a peach on the tree. This is a banana. This is a berry. This is cherry. That ss a haw. Thss ss ss a lemon. There ss a hickory on the tree. Thss ss an apple. That ss a pear. That ss an orange. That ss a kiwi fruit. Thss ssss an avocado. There ss a peach on the tree. Thss ss a banana. That ss a berry. That ss cherry. That ss a haw. Thss ss a lemon. There ss a hickory on the tree. Thss ss an apple. That ss a pear. That ss an orange. That ss a kiwi fruit. Thss ss an avocado. There ss a peach on the tree. This is a banana. This is a berry. This is cherry. That is a haw. Thss ss a lemon. There ss a hickory on the tree. Thss ss an apple. That ss a pear. That ss an orange. That ss a kiwi fruit. Thss ss an avocado. There ss a peach on the tree. Thss ss a banana. That ss a berry. That ss cherry. That ss a haw. Thss ss a lemon. There ss a hickory on the tree. Thss ss an apple. That ss a pear. That ss an orange. That ss a kiwi fruit. Thss ss ss an avocado. There ss a peach on the tree. This is a banana. This is a berry. This is cherry. This is a haw. Thss ss a lemon. There ss a hickory on the tree. Thss ss an apple. That ss a pear. That ss an orange. That ss a kiwi fruit. Thss ss an avocado. There ss a peach on the tree. Thss ss a banana. That ss a berry. That ss cherry. That ss a haw. Thss ss a lemon. There ss a hickory on the tree. Thss ss an apple. That ss a pear. That ss an orange. That ss a kiwi fruit. Thss ss an avocado. There ss a peach on the tree This is a banana. This is a berry. This is cherry. This is a haw. Thss is a lemon. There ss a hickory on the tree. Thss ss an apple. That ss a pear. That ss an orange. That ss a kiwi fruit. Thss ss an avocado. There ss a peach on the tree. Thss ss a banana. That ss a berry. That ss cherry. That ss a haw. Thss ss a lemon. There ss a hickory on the tree. Thss ss an apple. That ss a pear. That ss an orange. That ss a kiwi fruit. Thss ss an avocado. There ss a peach on the tree. This is a banana. This is a berry. This is cherry. This is a haw. This is a lemon. There ss a hickory on the tree. Thss ss an apple. That ss a pear. That ss an orange. That ss a kiwi fruit. Thss ss an avocado. There ss a peach on the tree. Thss ss a banana. That ss a berry. That ss cherry. That ss a haw. Thss ss a lemon. There ss a hickory on the
is
```

Thank you in advanced.  I've been working on this for many hours.

Comment: I downloaded and ran your program. I had to move `counter` and `allowedOnThread` above `num_substring` to prevent an implicit definition of the functions. I get a total of 55 but it's all done in a single thread (thread 2). All others report 0. Do you _have_ to define/use `allowedOnThread` and `counter` or are they just subfunctions you created to facilitate `num_substring`? I'm guessing that you only have to fill in `num_substring` and can do whatever else you want. Because the way you split up work between the threads is somewhat strange.

Comment: There is a better way to split up the work if you are allowed to refactor the code.Your prof's code (`readf`) is a bit newbie-like. Do you want to preserve the `.` so that (e.g.) `lemon.` is distinct from `lemon` or can `.` be considered a delimiter [like whitespace]? Do you need to preserve case so that (e.g.) `This` is distinct from `this`?

Comment: After I wrote my last comment, I just realized that `s2` the string to search for inside `s1` and you want to count the number of occurences of `s2` in `s1`. Would that be correct?

Comment: Are you required to use `calSubStringThread` with _just_ a `tid` argument? What I'd do is have the main thread calculate a position/length for each thread and pass that in separate struct instances to each thread.

Comment: @CraigEstey that is correct.

Comment: Note that you can't use `strtok` inside competing threads--it's _not_ thread safe. You should use `strtok_r` instead.

Comment: @CraigEstey I'm trying to keep everything the professor added as it is and just create my own.  I was considering adding it so it split the string into multiple sections and then process each section.  But I just don't know how.

Comment: If you can pass a `struct` pointer as the arg to `pthread_create` instead of `tid`, the code is simpler. It _can_ be done with just `tid` but the split code is slightly more complex (the individual threads have to do there own range calculations instead of having the main thread do them once). The tricky part is adjusting the ranges so that they do _not_ chop a word in the middle. That is, they increase/decrease starting offset and length to align with the whitespace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is prefaced by my top comments.

I had to refactor your code a bit.

I also had to modify some of the provided functions to allow debug `printf`

Based on your desired result of `55`, instead of `strtok`, you can/should use `strstr`. That's the only way I got the count to be correct.

I added a mutex so updates to `total` would not be trashed by thread collisions.

The key is the rewrite of `allowedOnThread` using a `struct` as I mentioned. Calculate a starting and ending offset for each segment for each thread, adjusting for before and after whitespace so that words are *not* chopped in the middle.

---

Hear is the refactored code. It is annotated. It allows each thread to calculate its range individually.

The code comes up with the correct answer but stopping on the `end` for each segment seems to be correct, but I might double check that.

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdatomic.h>

#define MAX 10240
#define NUM_THREADS  10

int n1, n2;
char *s1, *s2;
FILE *fp;
int countArray[NUM_THREADS] = { 0 };

pthread_mutex_t mutex;

int total = 0;

const char *delims = ",. \t\n";

struct range {
    size_t off;                         // starting offset
    size_t end;                         // ending offset (one past last char)
};

__thread int curtid;
__thread FILE *logxf;
#ifdef DEBUG
#define dbgprt(_fmt...) \
    _dbgprt(_fmt)
#else
#define dbgprt(_fmt...) \
    do { \
    } while (0)
#endif

#define prt(_lvl) \
    __attribute__((__format__(__printf__,_lvl,_lvl + 1)))

void prt(1)
_dbgprt(const char *fmt,...)
{
    char *bp;
    char buf[1000];
    va_list ap;

    if (logxf == NULL) {
        char logf[100];
        sprintf(logf,"log%2.2d",curtid);
        logxf = fopen(logf,"w");
        setlinebuf(logxf);
    }

    fprintf(logxf,"[%d] ",curtid);

    va_start(ap,fmt);
    bp += vfprintf(logxf,fmt,ap);
    va_end(ap);
}

//read input file and generate string s1/s2 and length n1/n2
int
readf(FILE * fp)
{
    if ((fp = fopen("strings.txt", "r")) == NULL) {
        printf("ERROR: can't open string.txt!\n");
        return 0;
    }
    s1 = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char) * MAX);
    if (s1 == NULL) {
        printf("ERROR: Out of memory!\n");
        return -1;
    }
    s2 = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char) * MAX);
    if (s1 == NULL) {
        printf("ERROR: Out of memory\n");
        return -1;
    }
    // read s1 s2 from the file

    s1 = fgets(s1, MAX, fp);
    s2 = fgets(s2, MAX, fp);
    // length of s1
    n1 = strlen(s1);
    // length of s2
    n2 = strlen(s2) - 1;

    // when error exit
    if (s1 == NULL || s2 == NULL || n1 < n2)
        return -1;
    return 0;
}

size_t
skip_to_delim(size_t off,const char *tag)
{
    char *str;

    dbgprt("skip_to_delim: ENTER off=%zu tag=%s\n",off,tag);

    str = &s1[off];
    off += strcspn(str,delims);

    dbgprt("skip_to_delim: EXIT off=%zu\n",off);

    return off;
}

int
allowedOnThread(int thread, struct range *seg)
{
    int threadMultiplier = n1 / NUM_THREADS;

    dbgprt("allowedOnThread: ENTER thread=%d\n",thread);

    // get starting offset
    do {
        seg->off = threadMultiplier * thread;

        // first thread always starts at offset 0
        if (thread == 0)
            break;

        // skip past a word and stop on a delimiter
        seg->off = skip_to_delim(seg->off,"off");
    } while (0);

    // get ending offset/length
    do {
        if (thread == (NUM_THREADS - 1)) {
            seg->end = n1;
            break;
        }

        // scan at least the amount we're allocated
        seg->end = seg->off + threadMultiplier;

        // skip past a word and stop on a delimiter
        seg->end = skip_to_delim(seg->end,"end");
    } while (0);

    dbgprt("allowedOnThread: EXIT thread=%d off=%zu end=%zu\n",
        thread,seg->off,seg->end);

    return 0;
}

int
num_substring(int t)
{
    //add your logic here
    //1, how to distribute different parts of string s1 into different threads
    //2, how to sum up the total number of substring from all threads

    dbgprt("num_substring: ENTER\n");

    struct range seg;
    allowedOnThread(t,&seg);

    char *str = &s1[seg.off];
    char *end = &s1[seg.end];

    char *token = str;
    size_t count = 0;

    // NOTE/FIXME -- this should be double checked to ensure that we're not
    // double counting by going beyond our range
    while (1) {
        // look for a substring match of s2 in s1
        token = strstr(token,s2);
        if (token == NULL)
            break;

        // don't intrude on next thread's segment
        if (token >= end)
            break;

        // advance the count
        count += 1;

        // point to start of next possible match point for s2
        token += n2;

        // stop when we go beyond the end of our thread's area
        if (token >= end)
            break;
    }

    // add to global count (under thread lock)
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    total += count;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);

    dbgprt("num_substring: EXIT count=%zu\n",count);

    return count;
}

void *
calSubStringThread(void *threadid)
{
    long tid = (long) threadid;

    curtid = tid + 1;

    dbgprt("calSubstringThread: ENTER\n");

    int num = num_substring(tid);

    dbgprt("calSubstringThread: EXIT num=%d\n",num);

    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

// docheck -- check with non-threaded algorithm
void
docheck(void)
{
    size_t count = 0;

    char *token = s1;
    while (1) {
        token = strstr(token,s2);
        if (token == NULL)
            break;

        count += 1;

        token += n2;
    }

    printf("docheck: count=%zu\n",count);
}

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    pthread_t threads[NUM_THREADS];
    int t, rc;

    pthread_mutex_init(&mutex,NULL);

    readf(fp);

    // get rid of newline
    s2[n2] = 0;
    dbgprt("main: s2='%s'\n",s2);

    docheck();

    for (t = 0; t < NUM_THREADS; t++) {
        rc = pthread_create(&threads[t], NULL, calSubStringThread,
            (void *) (size_t) t);
        if (rc) {
            printf("ERROR; return code from pthread_create() is %d\n", rc);
            exit(-1);
        }
    }

    for (t = 0; t < NUM_THREADS; t++) {
        pthread_join(threads[t], NULL);
    }

    printf("The number of substrings is: %d\n", total);

    return 0;
}
```

---

Here is the debug log output. (Note that I manually indented the logs based on the `ENTER/EXIT` messages).

```
==> log00 <==
[0] main: s2='is'

==> log01 <==
[1] calSubstringThread: ENTER
  [1] num_substring: ENTER
    [1] allowedOnThread: ENTER thread=0
      [1] skip_to_delim: ENTER off=479 tag=end
      [1] skip_to_delim: EXIT off=479
    [1] allowedOnThread: EXIT thread=0 off=0 end=479
  [1] num_substring: EXIT count=1
[1] calSubstringThread: EXIT num=1

==> log02 <==
[2] calSubstringThread: ENTER
  [2] num_substring: ENTER
    [2] allowedOnThread: ENTER thread=1
      [2] skip_to_delim: ENTER off=479 tag=off
      [2] skip_to_delim: EXIT off=479
      [2] skip_to_delim: ENTER off=958 tag=end
      [2] skip_to_delim: EXIT off=960
    [2] allowedOnThread: EXIT thread=1 off=479 end=960
  [2] num_substring: EXIT count=2
[2] calSubstringThread: EXIT num=2

==> log03 <==
[3] calSubstringThread: ENTER
  [3] num_substring: ENTER
    [3] allowedOnThread: ENTER thread=2
      [3] skip_to_delim: ENTER off=958 tag=off
      [3] skip_to_delim: EXIT off=960
      [3] skip_to_delim: ENTER off=1439 tag=end
      [3] skip_to_delim: EXIT off=1440
    [3] allowedOnThread: EXIT thread=2 off=960 end=1440
  [3] num_substring: EXIT count=3
[3] calSubstringThread: EXIT num=3

==> log04 <==
[4] calSubstringThread: ENTER
  [4] num_substring: ENTER
    [4] allowedOnThread: ENTER thread=3
      [4] skip_to_delim: ENTER off=1437 tag=off
      [4] skip_to_delim: EXIT off=1440
      [4] skip_to_delim: ENTER off=1919 tag=end
      [4] skip_to_delim: EXIT off=1920
    [4] allowedOnThread: EXIT thread=3 off=1440 end=1920
  [4] num_substring: EXIT count=4
[4] calSubstringThread: EXIT num=4

==> log05 <==
[5] calSubstringThread: ENTER
  [5] num_substring: ENTER
    [5] allowedOnThread: ENTER thread=4
      [5] skip_to_delim: ENTER off=1916 tag=off
      [5] skip_to_delim: EXIT off=1920
      [5] skip_to_delim: ENTER off=2399 tag=end
      [5] skip_to_delim: EXIT off=2402
    [5] allowedOnThread: EXIT thread=4 off=1920 end=2402
  [5] num_substring: EXIT count=5
[5] calSubstringThread: EXIT num=5

==> log06 <==
[6] calSubstringThread: ENTER
  [6] num_substring: ENTER
    [6] allowedOnThread: ENTER thread=5
      [6] skip_to_delim: ENTER off=2395 tag=off
      [6] skip_to_delim: EXIT off=2396
      [6] skip_to_delim: ENTER off=2875 tag=end
      [6] skip_to_delim: EXIT off=2876
    [6] allowedOnThread: EXIT thread=5 off=2396 end=2876
  [6] num_substring: EXIT count=6
[6] calSubstringThread: EXIT num=6

==> log07 <==
[7] calSubstringThread: ENTER
  [7] num_substring: ENTER
    [7] allowedOnThread: ENTER thread=6
      [7] skip_to_delim: ENTER off=2874 tag=off
      [7] skip_to_delim: EXIT off=2876
      [7] skip_to_delim: ENTER off=3355 tag=end
      [7] skip_to_delim: EXIT off=3356
    [7] allowedOnThread: EXIT thread=6 off=2876 end=3356
  [7] num_substring: EXIT count=7
[7] calSubstringThread: EXIT num=7

==> log08 <==
[8] calSubstringThread: ENTER
  [8] num_substring: ENTER
    [8] allowedOnThread: ENTER thread=7
      [8] skip_to_delim: ENTER off=3353 tag=off
      [8] skip_to_delim: EXIT off=3356
      [8] skip_to_delim: ENTER off=3835 tag=end
      [8] skip_to_delim: EXIT off=3835
    [8] allowedOnThread: EXIT thread=7 off=3356 end=3835
  [8] num_substring: EXIT count=8
[8] calSubstringThread: EXIT num=8

==> log09 <==
[9] calSubstringThread: ENTER
  [9] num_substring: ENTER
    [9] allowedOnThread: ENTER thread=8
      [9] skip_to_delim: ENTER off=3832 tag=off
      [9] skip_to_delim: EXIT off=3832
      [9] skip_to_delim: ENTER off=4311 tag=end
      [9] skip_to_delim: EXIT off=4311
    [9] allowedOnThread: EXIT thread=8 off=3832 end=4311
  [9] num_substring: EXIT count=9
[9] calSubstringThread: EXIT num=9

==> log10 <==
[10] calSubstringThread: ENTER
  [10] num_substring: ENTER
    [10] allowedOnThread: ENTER thread=9
      [10] skip_to_delim: ENTER off=4311 tag=off
      [10] skip_to_delim: EXIT off=4311
    [10] allowedOnThread: EXIT thread=9 off=4311 end=4799
  [10] num_substring: EXIT count=10
[10] calSubstringThread: EXIT num=10
```

---

> Thank you very much for explaining and helping me with this. I was wondering if you could explain to me how mutex works and why it's good practice to use it? – Bass Approved

This, from the C syntax, *seems* like an *atomic* operation:

```
total += count;
```

But, it's *not*. It's actually *three* operations:

```
temp = total;
temp += count;
total = temp;
```

Different threads will execute these in sequence. Normally (e.g. 99.44% of the time), these three operations will be executed by one thread without interference from another thread. If we have two threads (e.g. `A` and `B`), the "good" sequence is that the thread operations are "nicely" ordered:

```
thread A / cpu 0        thread B / cpu 1
--------------------    ------------------------
tempA = total;
tempA += countA;
total = tempA;
                        tempB = total;
                        tempB += countB;
                        total = tempB;
```

The *final* value for `total` would be: `total + countA + countB`, which is what we *want*.

But, if two threads are running *simultaneously* on different CPUs, they may intersperse these operations. We could have a sequence such as:

```
thread A / cpu 0        thread B / cpu 1
--------------------    ------------------------
tempA = total;
                        tempB = total;
tempA += countA;
                        tempB += countB;
total = tempA;
                        total = tempB;
```

In this case, at the end of the sequence, the final value of `total` would be: `total + countB` [which is *not* what we want]. (i.e.) The increment of `total` by `countA` [executed by thread `A`] would be lost/trashed!

In this case the threads are *racing* and thread `B` "won" the race.

Using a mutex [or other locking mechanism or using *atomic* operations] will prevent this.

A `pthread_mutex_lock` [loosely] is two operations: "request" and "grant". If the mutex is *not* held, these operations happen at the same time. If the mutex *is* held [by another thread], the "grant" is deferred in time. It is granted after the other thread has done a "release" (e.g. `pthread_mutex_unlock`). Here is the timeline:

```
thread A / cpu 0        thread B / cpu 1
--------------------    ------------------------
mutex requested
mutex granted
                        mutex requested
tempA = total;
tempA += countA;
total = tempA;
mutex released
                        mutex granted
                        tempB = total;
                        tempB += countB;
                        total = tempB;
                        mutex released
```

For a more detailed explanation, see my answer: [Threading Differences in Linux Subsystem For Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45764860/threading-differences-in-linux-subsystem-for-windows/45765091#45765091)

Another way to guarantee atomic update is the use of `stdatomic.h` primitives. See my answer: [multithreading with mutexes in c and running one thread at a time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65743084/multithreading-with-mutexes-in-c-and-running-one-thread-at-a-time/65744112#65744112)

Another solution is a "ticket lock". See my answer: [C Pthreads - issues with thread-safe queue implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41914822/c-pthreads-issues-with-thread-safe-queue-implementation/41915643#41915643)

Comment: Thank you very much for explaining and helping me with this.  I was wondering if you could explain to me how mutex works and why it's good practice to use it?