# Reimplementation of printf() using printf() in C

Tags: c, linux, gcc, embedded-linux, variadic-functions

I'm making a embedded linux project and I want to do a simple debug messages library where I can disable my debug messages (using pre-compilation directives) when my code is in production phase and substitute for some type of log in a database (in the future). I'm having trouble with reimplementation of `printf()` because of `va_list`. This is my code until now:

My source file:

```c
#include "debug_msgs.h"

#define ENABLE_DEBUG_MSGS   1U

#if ENABLE_DEBUG_MSGS

int print(const char *fmt, ...) {
    int n = -1;
    va_list ap;
    va_start(ap, fmt);
    n = printf(fmt, ap);
    va_end(ap);
    return n;
}

#else

int print(const char *fmt, ...) {
    return 0;
}

#endif
```

My header file:

```c
#ifndef DEBUG_MSGS_H
#define DEBUG_MSGS_H

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int print(const char *fmt, ...);

#endif
```

My problem is:
My implementation compiles (I know this doesn't mean nothing), but when I do a simple test like:

```c
int num1 = 10;
int num2 = 100;
int num3 = 1000;
float floating = 3.14;
char str[] = {"Please work, please"};
int number=-1;
number = print("\nTesting %d %d %d %f %s\n", num1, num2, num3, floating, str);
printf("\nnumber = %d\n",number); //Just to check the return
```

I get this output:

```
Testing -1095005212 100 -1095005212 -0.000002 H*� 

number = 52
```

Complementary informations:

This is my platform info:
`Linux mdm9607 3.18.44 #1 PREEMPT Tue Sep 13 19:45:33 UTC 2022 armv7l GNU/Linux`

My compiler info:
`arm-oe-linux-gnueabi-gcc`

My $CFLAGS:
 `-O2 -fexpensive-optimizations -frename-registers -fomit-frame-pointer -MMD -MP`

My $LDFLAGS:

`-Wl,-O1 -Wl,--hash-style=gnu -Wl,--as-needed`

```
LDFLAGS += -lumdp -lumdpcommon
LDFLAGS += -lpthread -lxml2 -lrt
LDFLAGS += -lm
```

Comment: You may want to use CPP macros instead of [or in conjunction with] a debug function. That's because if you have a call such as: `debug_print("%d\n",calculate_a_lot());` You have to call `calculate_a_lot` even if `debug_print` is a NOP. See my answer: [Distributed Computing with PThread Not Working](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68091540/5382650) for use of the debug macro along with the debug function.

Comment: You may want to turn on more compiler warnings, I'm surprised the version in your post compiled.

Comment: @CoffeeTableEspresso Good point, what other compiler warnings would you suggest-me?

Comment: `-Wall` (turns on a lot of warnings) and `-Werror` (turn warnings into errors) are two good flags to add. Later, if you find that `-Wall` gives you any warnings you don't want, you can turn _just that specific warning_ off.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Instead of `printf`, you should be using `vprintf` or `vfprintf` with a `va_list` argument:

```
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int print(const char *fmt, ...) {
    int n;
    va_list ap;
    va_start(ap, fmt);
    n = vprintf(fmt, ap);
    va_end(ap);
    return n;
}
```

The erroneous code compiles because `printf`, as a vararg function, can accept any argument types after the format string. Yet you can avoid type mismatches for `printf` arguments by enabling more compiler warnings: `gcc -Wall -Wextra -Werror` would at least complain about using `printf` with a non constant format string and would perform compile time type checking if the format string is a string literal.